# Schedulers.elastic() not using early generated threads

Tags: java, project-reactor

I've written web-server on spring-boot-2.0 which uses netty under the hood.
This application uses **Schedulers.elastic()** threads.

When it started, about 100 elastic threads were created. These threads were rarely used and we've had few loading.  But after a working day, the number of threads in elastic pool has increased to 1300. And now execution is on the elastic-1XXX, elastic-12XX threads, (name's numbers are above 100 and even 900).

Elastic, as I understand it, uses cachedThreadPool under the hood.
Why have new elastic threads been created and why has task switched to new threads?

What is the criteria for adding new trends?
And why haven't  old threads (elastic-XX, elastic-1xx) been shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: i was using **Schedulers.elastic()** for non-blocking operations, while there were no such operations . When i had removed elastic(), my service started to working correctly (without elastic's threads).

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the type of workload, the maximum concurrency, burst and average task duration, it’s really hard to tell if there’s a problem here.

By definition the elastic scheduler is creating an unbounded number of threads, as long as new tasks are added to the queue.

If the workload is bursty, with night concurrency at regular times, then it’s n unexpected to find a large number of threads. You could leverage the `newElastic` variants to reduce the TTL (default is 60s).

Again, without more information it’s hard to tell but your workload might not fit this scheduler. If your workload is CPU bound, the parallel scheduler is a better fit. The elastic one is tailored for IO/latency bound tasks.